# Remove the Packages completely leaving no file?

Tags: 14.04, package-management, uninstall

I have uninstalled a package and i have added the ppa via terminal for example.

I have to know that the packages have uninstalled successfully without leaving any file in my computer.

Is there any Command line to check it whether it was removed without leaving a single file?

I'm using Ubuntu14.04

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If the package maintainer is a good package maintainer, then the following should be enough:

To remove a package completely, use

```
 sudo apt-get purge package_name
```

But it can be, that some configuration files exists in your home folder. This files will not be removed by the command above.

As I don't know your package name, simply start a search

```
find ~ -maxdepth 1 -iname '*package_name*''
```

And

```
find ~/.config -iname '*package_name*''
```

Don't remove the `*` from the search pattern. Change only the `package_name`.

But if you in doubt, start a full scan

```
sudo   find / -iname '*package_name*''
```

Comment: also, `apt-file list package_name` will list all the files a package installs although it doesn't include generated config files

Comment: The installed software may have created other files the package manager can not know about.